# List resolver with tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list:

```
List = [('4022-a751',), ('0bfc-4d53',)]
```

And want to resolve it into the output below:

```
Output = ['4022-a751','0bfc-4d53']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make a flat list out of list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tuple can be manipulated like an array with index.

```py
input_arr = [('4022-a751',), ('0bfc-4d53',)]
output_arr = [a[0] for a in input_arr]

print(output_arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should read about [List Comprehensions in Python](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python)

```
list_ = [('4022-a751',), ('0bfc-4d53',)]
res = [x for item in list_ for x in item]
```

Output

```
['4022-a751', '0bfc-4d53']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
old_list= [('4022-a751',), ('0bfc-4d53',)]
new_list = [''.join(i) for i in old_list]
print(new_list)
```